# How to make all combinations of columns

Tags: r, loops, subset, combinations

I have a data frame consisting of 46 variables, and what I would like to do is making subsets per all possible combinations of 2 variables.

For example, if I had a data frame consisting of 3 variables  "A", "B", "C", making 3 subsets with variables A and B, A and C, B and C would be my goal.

I would like to assign each of those subsets as covariates of a regression model so that I can try all the combination of 2 variables as covariates.

All I can think of is using loop, but I would appreciate it if anyone could teach me how to do it!

Comment: A nested loop is perfect for this, and for each iteration the inner lop should increase the start index so that it does not match existing sets, for example you don't need to match both A-C and C-A.

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: @sorifiend Thank you so much for giving me an idea. I would really appreciate it if you could give me a short example code...I'm a beginner and it's still difficult for me to write loops...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from the comments, you can do this with nested loops.

This will loop the data and print out pairs without any duplicates:

```
#your data
char_vec <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")

#values to track the outer loop
i = 1

#use -1 to the length because we cant make a pair from only the single last value
while(i <= length(char_vec)-1){

    #value to track the inner loop
    #start at i+1 to make sure that we don't repeat data
    j = i+1
    while(j <= length(char_vec)){
        #print your data or do whatever you need with it
        #using sep="" will remove the space from joining the values using the paste command
        print(paste(char_vec[i],char_vec[j],sep=""))

        #increase for the next loop
        j <- j + 1
    }
    #increase for the next loop
    i <- i + 1 
}
```

And the output looks like this:

```
[1] "AB"
[1] "AC"
[1] "AD"
[1] "BC"
[1] "BD"
[1] "CD"
```

Answer (score 1):

`combn` could help preparing the list of combinations :

```
apply(combn(c("A","B","C"),2),2,function(x) as.formula(paste0("y~",x[1],'+',x[2])))

[[1]]
y ~ A + B
<environment: 0x0000027286e851c8>

[[2]]
y ~ A + C
<environment: 0x000002728897a380>

[[3]]
y ~ B + C
<environment: 0x000002728692adc0>
```

You could then use `lapply` to evaluate the different formulas.

For example with `mtcars`:

```r
variables <- setdiff(colnames(mtcars),"cyl")
cbn <- apply(combn(variables,2),2,function(x) as.formula(paste0("cyl~",x[1],'+',x[2])))
lapply(cbn,function(x) {summary(eval(substitute(lm(y,mtcars),list(y=x))))})
#> [[1]]
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = cyl ~ mpg + disp, data = mtcars)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -1.3002 -0.6138  0.1776  0.5486  1.1406 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)  5.917863   1.255293   4.714 5.61e-05 ***
#> mpg         -0.092206   0.041352  -2.230   0.0337 *  
#> disp         0.009198   0.002011   4.574 8.27e-05 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.7364 on 29 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.8409, Adjusted R-squared:   0.83 
#> F-statistic: 76.66 on 2 and 29 DF,  p-value: 2.647e-12
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = cyl ~ mpg + hp, data = mtcars)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -1.5641 -0.4721 -0.1099  0.6273  1.3585 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)  7.629183   1.226285   6.221 8.69e-07 ***
#> mpg         -0.153574   0.039052  -3.933  0.00048 ***
#> hp           0.011205   0.003433   3.264  0.00281 ** 
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.8263 on 29 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.7998, Adjusted R-squared:  0.7859 
#> F-statistic: 57.91 on 2 and 29 DF,  p-value: 7.459e-11
#> 
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = cyl ~ mpg + drat, data = mtcars)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -1.8180 -0.4772  0.2271  0.6694  1.3862 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept) 13.03441    1.15565  11.279 4.02e-12 ***
#> mpg         -0.20753    0.03737  -5.554 5.45e-06 ***
#> drat        -0.74449    0.42121  -1.767   0.0877 .  
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.918 on 29 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.7528, Adjusted R-squared:  0.7358 
#> F-statistic: 44.16 on 2 and 29 DF,  p-value: 1.581e-09
#>
```

Comment: @Umi, glad I could help! If this answered your question, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so that others know it worked and can also benefit from it.

Comment: Sorry, I need to know some more  and I added a question below. I would really appreciate it if you could give me a response to it too...